# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ ошибка

Tags: android, kotlin, list, retrofit

```
data class MovieListResultEntity(
@SerializedName("adult")
val isAdult: Boolean,

@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
val backdropPath: String,

@SerializedName("genre_ids")
val genreIds: List<Int>,

val id: Int,

@SerializedName("original_language")
val originalLanguage: String,

@SerializedName("original_title")
val originalTitle: String,

val overview: String,

val popularity: Float,

@SerializedName("poster_path")
val posterPath: String,

@SerializedName("release_date")
val releaseDate: String,

val title: String,

val video: Boolean,

@SerializedName("vote_average")
val voteAverage: Float,

@SerializedName("vote_count")
val voteCount: Int
```

)

```
data class PageOfMoviesEntity(
val page: Int,

val results: List<MovieListResultEntity>,

@SerializedName("total_pages")
val totalPages: Int,

@SerializedName("total_results")
val totalResults: Int
```

)

```
object MoviesClient {

private val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

val api: MoviesApi by lazy {
    retrofit.create(MoviesApi::class.java)
}
```

}

```
interface MoviesApi {

@GET("3/movie/popular?api_key=cbf6b34df260fad6fb3b7a41ef4b067c&language=en-US&page=1")
suspend fun getFirstPageOfPopularMovies(): Response<List<PageOfMoviesEntity>>
```

}

На форумах вижу что нужно как-то переинициализировать лист, но как догнать не могу.

Comment: Нужно исправить модель для JSON - в ошибке утверждается что у вас объявлен массив/список там где на самом деле объект. Без примера JSON-строки сказать больше нечего. Скорее всего исправить нужно в интерфейсе `Response<List<PageOfMoviesEntity>>` -> `Response<PageOfMoviesEntity>`

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибка была именно в том, что нужно было указывать тип модели а не листа моделей.